# How to stop and start a whole cluster Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, swarm

My question is simple: I need to stop all nodes of a cluster swarm, how to stop properly it before shutdown nodes ?

Next, how to restart it properly ?

In my cluster (10 nodes), there are at least 60 services

Answer (score 0):

If all services are in the same [docker stack](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/stack-deploy/) you can stop all services running on the nodes using: `docker stack rm`.

To start it again (restart) you run `docker stack deploy`

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to 'suspend' a stack and to reload it when cluster is available ?